# Scattered 2D array to contiguous 2D array transformation (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to make a generic function in C that takes a 2D array of ANY type and copies it into a contiguous memory block. ( I need this function for Aggregate operations on MPI on my complex datatypes).

Imagine I have the following integer array

```
int n = 5;
int m = 6;

int** int_array = (int**) malloc(n* sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
     int_array[i] = (int *) malloc(m * sizeof(int) );
```

In this type of memory allocation one cannot, in principle, hope to access the , say i,j-th entry of int_array using the following pointer arithmetics

```
int value = (*lcc)[i*m+j];
```

Therefore I implemented a function that basically allocates a new memory block and neatly orders the entries of int_array so that the above indexing should work.

```
void linearize(char*** array, int n, int m,unsigned int size_bytes){


        char* newarray = (char*)malloc(m*n*size_bytes);

        //copy array!
        for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j = 0;j<m*size_bytes;j++)
            {   
                newarray[i*m*size_bytes+j] = (*array)[i][j];
            }

        //swap pointers and free old memory!    
        for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        {   
            char * temp = (*array)[i];
            (*array)[i] = newarray + i*m*size_bytes ;
            free(temp);
        }

}
```

I wanted to make the above function to work with any kind of array type, hence I used char pointers to do operations byte by byte. I tested the function and so far it works, but I am not sure about memory deallocation.

Does free(temp) free the whole memory pointed to by int_array[i], that is the m*sizeof(int) bytes accessible from int_array[i] or only the first m bytes (since it thinks that our array is of type char rather than in) ? Or simply put, "Does the linearize function induce any memory leaks? "

Thank you in advance!

****EDIT****

As suggested by Nicolas Barbey, I ran a valgrind checks for memory leaks and it found none.

So to summarize the main points that I found difficult to understand about the behaviour of the program were:

in the function linearize does the following code induce memory leaks:

```
char * temp = (*array)[i];
(*array)[i] = newarray + i*m*size_bytes ;
free(temp);
```

NO!! somehow gnu compiler is smart enough to know how many bytes pointed to by "temp" to free. Originally I was afraid that if I *array[i] is a pointer of type int* , for example, that points to a memory location with say 5 ints = 5*4 bytes, the free(temp) is going to free only the first five bytes of that memory.

Another point to make is : how to free the already linearized array? that is if you have:

```
// first initialize the array.

int** array = (int**)malloc(5*sizeof(int*);
for(int i = 0; i< 5;i++)
   array[i] = ( int* ) malloc(5*sizeof(int));

//now a call to linearize
linearize(&array,5,5,sizeof(int));

... do some work with array ....

// now time to free array
free(array[0]);
free(array);
//suffices to free all memory pointed to by array[i] and as well as the memory allocated
// for the pointers.
```

Thanks for the discussion and the suggestions.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. -- apart from that: call `free()` exactly once per `malloc()`, then there'll be no leaks.

Comment: That's not a two dimensional array. It is an array of pointers to arrays. They're *not* the same. And you don't want to be [a three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) if you can at-all avoid it. (and you can).

Comment: do you mean instead of  char * temp = (char*)(*array)[i];
  char * temp = (*array)[i]; ?

Comment: @WhozCraig No need to pick on me. AND NO, I CANT avoid being a three star programmer, since the input I have to handle is THREE-STAR-PROGRAMMERS-ONLY INPUT.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but do you know you can check that your program does not have leaks with valgrind ? http://valgrind.org/

Comment: @kennywise If its come down to the mere mention of any inaccuracies as being classified as "picking on" someone, then we truly have reached the abyss. It was not the intent, and bummer if you took it as such. You're not the only one reading this, and a neophyte that skims this question shouldn't have to walk away thinking they know what a 2D array is, when there is none here. Finally, your `linearize()`has no need for a third level of indirection. If there was a `*array = ...` in there, you almost have a case, though even then a non-void return value would eliminate that too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `free()` exactly one call per `malloc()` inorder to be no memory leaks. Which means in your case `int_array` is passed to linearize function allocates a block of memory other than `int_array` allocation, therefore you need to loop over `int_array[i]` freeing each `int*` that you traverse followed by free'ing `int_array` itself. Also you need to free block created in linearize function too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly slimmer version using actual two dimensional arrays:

```
void * linearize(void** array, int n, int m,unsigned int size_bytes){

    char (*newarray)[m * size_bytes] = malloc(m*n*size_bytes);

    //copy array!
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i<n;i++) {
        memcpy(newarray[i], array[i], sizeof(*newarray));
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return newarray;
}
```

Use:

```
int (*newarray)[m] = linearize(array, n, m, sizeof(**int_array));
int value = newarray[i][j];
// or
value = newarray[0][i*m + j];
// or
value = ((int *)newarray)[i*m + j];
```